# Sum of rows in the matrix with the biggest minimal

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, greedy

I have two matrix, let me call them ones_matrix and zero_matrix

I need to create new list which is sum of best 20 rows from this matrixes like 10 rows from first and 10 rows from second where minimal element in summed list is biggest.

So it is greedy alghorhytm where I am choosing the best row from matrix to add on each step. 10 times for onesMatrix and 10 times for zero_matrix and 10 times for ones_matrix and also execluding repetitions of rows.

Each time we need to add something we haven't added before.
My input is two 64 x 128 matrix which contains only ones and zeros.

So my answer cant be bigger then 20, because I am summing 20 rows with zeros and ones and sum of 20 rows which contains only ones is 64*[20] with minimal element - 20.
 Here is my code:

```
ignored=set()
res=np.zeros(128)
for i in range(10):
    j=best(res,ones_matrix,ignored)
    res=res+ones_matrix[j]
    ignored.add(j)
    j = best(res, zero_matrix,ignored)
    res = res + zero_matrix[j]
    ignored.add(j)

def best(res,matrix,ignored):
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    matrix[i]=matrix[i]+res
m=min(matrix[0])
index=0
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    if (min(matrix[i])>=m and i not in ignored):
        index=i
        m=min(matrix[i])
print(index)
return index
```

These matrix are contains only zeros and nulls, so max element in my new row cant be bigger then 20( cause I am adding 20 rows which contains from nulls and zeros). But when I use

```
print(min(res))
```

I am getting huge value like 44266.0
How can I make this work?

Best row is row with the biggest minimal element.

Comment: What is a best row? Could you add some small sample input and the expected output?

Comment: Added little comment before code, but data is too big to paste it here and there are no little examlpes from 4-5  tiny rows.

Comment: 1. Your indentation is wrong, so this code should not work. 2. Where do you code? In my environments I always had to define functions _before_ their use, so again, this code shouldn't work. 3. If you want to find anything in a 128x64 array - why do you use a loop with ten iterations doing the same thing over and over again? Iterating over all these elements is already enough. I'd suggest to calculate your min value for each row and then take the top 10 of the sorted indices of this result.

Comment: As far as I can see, you change the content of your matrices in `matrix[i]=matrix[i]+res`. Can you check if they still consist of ones or zeros only after running your code? And still: I do not really understand the algorithm, especially what "best" exactly means. Isn't the biggest minimum element of rows of ones and zeros only always `0` - except there is a row without a single zero, then it is `1`...?